# MySQL script triggers Error #1241

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the script below, which is supposed to get a price for an array of ID's that has been provided.

But it needs to get `1` price per `ID`, and the tricky part is, that I want to have the ability to have scheduled price updates.

This mean that it needs to take the price that is `<= UTC_TIMESTAMP` smaller or equal to the current time.

```
SELECT 
`product_pricing`.`wo_id`,
`product_pricing`.`currency` AS price2_currency,
`product_pricing`.`price` AS price2,
`product_pricing`.`formula_id`,
`product_pricing`.`vat_calculated` AS price2_vat_calculated,
`product_pricing`.`vat_id`,
`product_pricing`.`timestamp_valid`,

`product_price_formulas`.`formula_id`,
`product_price_formulas`.`formula` price2_formula

FROM 
`product_pricing`

LEFT JOIN `product_price_formulas` 
ON `product_pricing`.`formula_id` = `product_price_formulas`.`formula_id`

WHERE 
`product_pricing`.`wo_id` IN (

    SELECT 
    `product_pricing`.`wo_id`,
    `product_pricing`.`timestamp_valid`

    FROM `product_pricing`

    WHERE 
    `product_pricing`.`wo_id` 
        IN ('015724', '028791', '015712', '015715', '015717', '039750', '028791')
    AND `product_pricing`.`timestamp_valid` <= UTC_TIMESTAMP

    ORDER BY `product_pricing`.`timestamp_valid` DESC        
 )
```

Is this possible?

---

Sample data: Current output

```
——————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
 | wo_id    | price2    | timestamp_valid 
——————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
 | 028791   | 8000      | 2018-03-20 19:55:41
 | 028791   | 6000      | 2018-04-01 19:55:41
 | 028791   | 4000      | 2018-04-20 19:55:41
 | 015724   | 3000      | 2018-04-18 19:55:41
 | 015724   | 1500      | 2018-03-01 19:55:41
 ....
```

Wanted output:

```
——————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
 | wo_id    | price2    | timestamp_valid 
——————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
 | 028791   | 6000      | 2018-04-01 19:55:41
 | 015724   | 1500      | 2018-03-01 19:55:41
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your issue is on the `IN` clause.

You select two field in `IN` clause.

**EDIT**

You need to self join a subquery by `wo_id` and Max `timestamp_valid`.

```
SELECT 
    `product_pricing`.`wo_id`,
    `product_pricing`.`currency` AS price2_currency,
    `product_pricing`.`price` AS price2,
    `product_pricing`.`formula_id`,
    `product_pricing`.`vat_calculated` AS price2_vat_calculated,
    `product_pricing`.`vat_id`,
    `product_pricing`.`timestamp_valid`,
    `product_price_formulas`.`formula_id`,
    `product_price_formulas`.`formula` price2_formula
FROM 
`product_pricing`
LEFT JOIN `product_price_formulas` ON `product_pricing`.`formula_id` = `product_price_formulas`.`formula_id`
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
        `product_pricing`.`wo_id`,
        MAX(`timestamp_valid`) AS MaxDate
    FROM `product_pricing`
    WHERE 
        `product_pricing`.`timestamp_valid` <= UTC_TIMESTAMP
    GROUP BY 
        `product_pricing`.`wo_id`
)as temp ON temp.wo_id = `product_pricing`.`wo_id` AND temp.MaxDate = `product_pricing`.`timestamp_valid`
WHERE  
    `product_pricing`.`wo_id` IN ('015724', '028791', '015712', '015715', '015717', '039750', '028791')
```

Comment: Huh, yes it worked like that however...it returns multiple prices per ID. It needs to return only 1 which is `product_pricing.timestamp_valid <= UTC_TIMESTAMP`

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and your expect result that will be helpful:)

Comment: Added. Please take a look at the question

Comment: @Borsn Sorry late for reply,The edit wish can help you:)

Comment: It's returning all values for each id. Instead of filtering it out by `timestamp_valid` like in the wanted output. What does MAX do in this context?

Comment: @Borsn The subquery `MAX` can get most close at `UTC_TIMESTAMP` by `WHERE` clause. I edit my answer you can try that

Comment: Works great now! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT pp.*, ppf.formula_id, ppf.formula as price2_formula
FROM product_pricing pp LEFT JOIN
     product_price_formulas ppf
     ON pp.formula_id = ppf.formula_id    
WHERE (pp.wo_id, pp.timestamp_valid) IN
          (SELECT pp2.wo_id, MAX(pp2.timestamp_valid)
           FROM product_pricing pp2
           WHERE pp2.wo_id IN ('015724', '028791', '015712', '015715', '015717', '039750', '028791') AND
                pp2.timestamp_valid <= UTC_TIMESTAMP
          );
```

The `ORDER BY` makes no sense in the subquery, so this is my best guess as to what you want.

I left this with your structure of using `IN`, but I would use a correlated subquery and `=`:

```
WHERE pp.timestamp_valid = (SELECT MAX(pp2.timestamp_valid)
                            FROM product_pricing pp2
                            WHERE pp2.wo_id = pp.wo_id AND
                                  pp2.timestamp_valid <= UTC_TIMESTAMP
                           ) AND
      pp2.wo_id IN ('015724', '028791', '015712', '015715', '015717', '039750', '028791');
```

Comment: You only seem to be selecting the formula. How would I add all of the other rows I have in the original `SELECT`?

Comment: @Borsn . . . You can list them in the `select`.  I shorted that to `pp.*`.

Answer (score 0):

You could JOIN product_pricing with a derived result set of the most recent valid_timestamp records.

If we ignore the product_pricing_formula table for now (since you didn't include it in your specimen data and result) that would give.

```
SELECT 
p.`wo_id`,
p.`price` AS price2,
p.`timestamp_valid`
FROM `product_pricing` p
JOIN (SELECT wo_id, MAX(timestamp_valid) AS max_valid_ts
      FROM `product_pricing`
      WHERE `timestamp_valid` <= UTC_TIMESTAMP
      GROUP BY wo_id) d
ON (d.wo_id = p.wo_id AND d.max_valid_ts = p.timestamp_valid)
WHERE p.`wo_id` IN (015724, 028791);
```

Try it on [Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d9212/12)